# recursive relations django queires

Tags: python, django, django-models

I created a many to many recursive relationship in Django.  How do you query the recursive field subfolder in the code below. That is given a folder list all its subfolder?

```
class Folder(models.Model):
"""Folder Model, can contain many folders and many files"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    subfolders = models.ManyToManyField('Folder', blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *self-referencing* many-to-many field works the same way as a conventional one. Given a `folder` you can access all subfolders with:

```
sub_folders = folder.subfolders.all()
```

Comment: in folder.subfolders.all() where does folder come from?

Comment: Your question reads: *That is given a **folder** list all its subfolder*